# Looking for Chart control in winform .net 6

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

Please need your help.
I used Chart control in c#, winforms .net framework 4.8. it is a cool control, very easy to present and to maintaining.
I'm looking the same things in .net 6 msvs 2022
couldn't find.
does anyone has an advice please?

Thanks
Tami

Comment: It is deprecated for .NET Core, an unsupported port [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization).  No design-time support.

Comment: Do you know what the reason is? And what the alternative recomended by microsoft?      Btw, the code is works well on .net 6, just not support by the designer